# It is possible to get total storage capacity?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card

i know how to get free capacity on internal memory and on external storage.

But i want to know max capacity of internal memory and max capacity of external storage, but i can't find any info about it on google

it is possible to achieve it?

thanks

Comment: so like some sort of function, that adds this two values together... ;-)

Comment: you didn't understand me, i want max capacity of internal, and max capacity for external, i dont want the sum of internal + external....

Answer (score 7):

Some new methods were introduced in API 18.  This is the code I used to get  total storage (internal + external).

`private static final long KILOBYTE = 1024;`

```
StatFs internalStatFs = new StatFs( Environment.getRootDirectory().getAbsolutePath() );
long internalTotal;
long internalFree;

StatFs externalStatFs = new StatFs( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() );
long externalTotal;
long externalFree;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    internalTotal = ( internalStatFs.getBlockCountLong() * internalStatFs.getBlockSizeLong() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
    internalFree = ( internalStatFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * internalStatFs.getBlockSizeLong() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
    externalTotal = ( externalStatFs.getBlockCountLong() * externalStatFs.getBlockSizeLong() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
    externalFree = ( externalStatFs.getAvailableBlocksLong() * externalStatFs.getBlockSizeLong() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
}
else {
    internalTotal = ( (long) internalStatFs.getBlockCount() * (long) internalStatFs.getBlockSize() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
    internalFree = ( (long) internalStatFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) internalStatFs.getBlockSize() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
    externalTotal = ( (long) externalStatFs.getBlockCount() * (long) externalStatFs.getBlockSize() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
    externalFree = ( (long) externalStatFs.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) externalStatFs.getBlockSize() ) / ( KILOBYTE * KILOBYTE );
}

long total = internalTotal + externalTotal;
long free = internalFree + externalFree;
long used = total - free;
```

Comment: i m using api level 16 and this function is giving me logcat  11-22 14:29:45.933: D/MainActivity(6092): getTotalInternalExternalMemorySize method called
11-22 14:29:45.933: D/MainActivity(6092): if block
11-22 14:29:45.933: D/MainActivity(6092): total Memory:-704 MB
11-22 14:29:45.933: D/MainActivity(6092): free Memory:-641 MB
11-22 14:29:45.933: D/MainActivity(6092): used Memory:-63 MB

Answer (score 5):

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = stat.getBlockSizeLong() * stat.getBlockCountLong();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/7O3plkY6QFg)

Also, use this for internal size.

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will not work on all phones, most phones return the total amount of memory available to the user, less system memory. you might try using the 'df -h' linux command in a c++ method using the NDK, but some phone make that a system (su) command only. So the long and short of it is you can't.

Answer (score 0):

**[StatFs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html)** - Retrieve overall information about the space on a filesystem. This is a wrapper for Unix statvfs().

From  API level 18 we use

```
long getTotalBytes - The total number of bytes supported by the file system.
```

For older API use

```
int getBlockCount ()
int getBlockSize ()

StatFs stat = new StatFs(**path**);
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
```

As path You use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())(), please review this value. In devices with multiple shared/external storage directories, this directory represents the primary storage that the user will interact with.

You need use string values of path like this:
"/mnt/external_sd/"
"/mnt/extSdCard/"

You can retreive list of all **/mnt/** devices and use one of this values.

```
File allMounted = new File("/mnt/");
if(allMounted.isDirectory()){ 
String[] dirs = allMounted.list();...}
```

or something like

```
var myfile=new Java.IO.File("storage/");
var listOfStorages=myfile.ListFiles();
```

or

```
String[] externals = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE").split(":");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    val stat = StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path)

    val available = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        stat.blockCountLong * stat.blockSizeLong
    } else {
        stat.blockCount.toLong() * stat.blockSize.toLong()
    }
    val totalInMB = bytesAvailable / (1024*1024)
```