# Storage Summary Interface on Gingerbread

Tags: android, interface, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to make such an interface like the storage summary section in Gingerbread. It's like the seekbar or progress bar but you can not customize it, it just simply show the certain amount of something out of the total amount.

Here's the pic

[image: Storage Summary on Gingerbread]

Can anyone tell me what to call such a interface or how to make that? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  We'll help you with problems, but we won't do it for you.

Comment: I don't even know what that kind of interface called. If I know perhaps I should have started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the UI, you can use `ProgressBars`. Should be easy to calculate what values to place in each of them, but you will surely need the following:

Total Storage capacity

[It is possible to get total storage capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531806/it-is-possible-to-get-total-storage-capacity)

Size of a directory

[How can I get the size of a folder on SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040912/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-a-folder-on-sd-card-in-android)