# Obtain “About Phone” details programmatically

Tags: android

I am wondering how to obtain the details located in the "About Phone" section in the settings of Android devices programmatically.

More specifically I like to obtain the stated storage capacity of the device i.e 64GB in the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Get Hardware Information Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496872/android-get-hardware-information-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Using Build class you can get all of this information

For example, Build.HARDWARE etc. Check the docs
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

And to see specifically the storage capacity check out this question [It is possible to get total storage capacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531806/it-is-possible-to-get-total-storage-capacity)

Comment: Build does not contain all of this information, it does not contain storage for example. I am wondering if it is manufacturer specific?

Comment: That is also not the stated storage capacity, that will only show the storage capacity of the primary storage mount available to the current user. So for example for a 64GB device that method would return ~54GB.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, you'll get the available storage capacity and the other will be reserved for different os partitions. As I did my research on this topic, there is no legit way to obtain the stated capacity only the available for user