# How to get the total storage size of the device?

Tags: java, android

Currenty I get the total storage size with:

```
public static long getTotalSize(String path) {
    try {
        final StatFs statFs = new StatFs(path);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            return statFs.getTotalBytes();
        } else {
            return statFs.getBlockCount() * statFs.getBlockSize();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As `path` I am using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`. This results in 54,0 GB. Problem is that the device has a size of 64 GB.

How to detect the missing 10 GB?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531806/it-is-possible-to-get-total-storage-capacity

Answer (score 0):

**[StatFs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html)** - Retrieve overall information about the space on a filesystem. This is a wrapper for Unix statvfs().

From  API level 18 we use

```
long getTotalBytes - The total number of bytes supported by the file system.
```

For older API use

```
int getBlockCount ()
int getBlockSize ()

StatFs stat = new StatFs(**path**);
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
```

As path You use [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())(), please review this value. In devices with multiple shared/external storage directories, this directory represents the primary storage that the user will interact with.

You need use string values of path like this:
"/mnt/external_sd/"
"/mnt/extSdCard/"

You can retreive list of all **/mnt/** devices and use one of this values.

```
File mntDir = new File("/mnt/");
if(mntDir.isDirectory()){ 
String[] dirList = mntDir.list();...}
```

or something like

```
var file=new Java.IO.File("storage/");
var listOfStorages=file.ListFiles();
```

or

```
String[] externals = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE").split(":");
```